# Amazon AWS putBucketLogging parameters in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am writing script that connects to amazon S3 storage. The script is supposed to create 2 buckets:

1. Bucket is for data
2. Bucket is for logs

I successfully created both buckets but I can't set up logging. Below is shown code I use for enabling bucket logging

```
 $result = $client->putBucketLogging(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'LoggingEnabled' => array(
            'TargetBucket' => $bucket . '-LOG',
            'TargetGrants'=>array(
              'Grantee'=>array(
                  'DisplayName'=>'user.name',
                  'Type'=>'CanonicalUser'
              ),  
            ),
             'TargetPrefix' => 'LOG-',
        ),
    ));
```

In amazon AWS API for PHP version 2 is written that Bucket, LoggingEnabled and Type are mandatory. But the documentation does not say how to exactly implement there parameters.

Could you please help me with structure of config array for **putBucketLogging** method?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the service's API documents as a reference, which sometimes contain more details about how to specifically structure some of the data types for requests. The [S3 API docs for PUT Bucket Logging](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTlogging.html) have more details about how to specify the grantee.

Also, you should not use capital letters in bucket names (See [Rules for Bucket Naming](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html#bucketnamingrules)).

Answer (score 0):

After searching in manuals the php array for method **putBucketLogging** is

```
    $result = $client->putBucketLogging(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'LoggingEnabled' => array(
            'TargetBucket' => $bucket . '-log',
            'TargetGrants' => array(
                'Grant' => array(
                    'Grantee' => array(
                        'Type' => 'AmazonCustomerByEmail',
                        'EmailAddress' => 'email@email.com',
                    ),
                    'Permission' => 'FULL_CONTROL',
                ),
            ),
            'TargetPrefix' => 'log-',
        ),
    ));
```

However enabling logging fails with exception that tells me I have to set permissions on log bucket...